# Files in sub-directories of Boost library do not load (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

I'm using Visual Studio. I just watched a tutorial on how to use libraries with the boost library in C++, and I added C:\Program Files\Cpp_Libs\boost_1_74_0 to Include Additional Libraries property in my project.

It works with optional.hpp in the boost_1_74_0\boost directory, but it doesn't work with the files in the boost_1_74_0\boost\archive directory or other sub-directories.

VS is recommending I install vspkg to install boost-serialization, but is there a way I can do it without this?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Does your code compile? Sometimes Intellisense gets it wrong.

Comment: I wish I tested this before, I eventually ended up installing vspkg but when I get an SSD and have to reinstall everything I look out for that.